# SSL website in my program

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I want to make some program that can use website 
I try using the webkitdotnet but it not work with SSL website like google or other websites
can someone help me solve that problem

I try also the webBrowser in C#
with this

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);

 public bool AcceptAllCertifications(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certification, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

but it do some problem with JS scripts so I also can't use it

someone knows any other control, DLC that I can use for the software

I am using Forms for that.

Comment: I suggest reading the [*SO-FAQ*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) where it clearly states asking for 3rd party libraries in forbidden.

Comment: Maybe a better approach is to create an MCVE (see [ask]) for the webkit version, which demonstrates a non-working ssl site. Answers either fix that problem or propose a better suitable library if you indicate you're open for that, similar as I explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208460/158100)